# CSS Specificity Order

Tags: css

I have two css classes in a codebase and I'm unsure why one is being chosen over the other, I thought the specifity of my second one was stronger. Is anyone able to explain?

The CSS class that it's choosing is -

`td, th, table {   border-collapse: collapse;   border: 1px solid #999; }`

And the CSS that I want it to use is -

`table.cancellation {     border: none;    }`

I thought as the second one had a class selector it would have a stronger specificity, why am I wrong?

Comment: you're not wrong , the latter has higher specificity

Comment: Then I have no idea why the border is still being applied, :( There must be something else going on! Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure `table.cancellation` is the correct selector? Open the Console tab in your browser's dev tools and run `document.querySelector("table.cancellation")` and see if it returns an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the style for the *table*, but not the *cells*.

In the first table, everything has a red border.

In the second table, the table has a blue border, but since `border-collapse:collapse` is set, the red of the `td` & `td` appear above it.

In the third table, `border-collapse` is set to `separate` and you can see that the table does truly have a blue border.

In the last table, the styles for `td` and `th` are also overwritten - giving a borderless table.

```css
th,
td,
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:1rem;// just for looks
}
table.table {
  border-color: blue
}

table.separate{
border-collapse:separate;
}

table.none,
table.none th,
table.none td{
border:none
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Head
    </th>
    <td>
      cell
    </td>
</table>

<table class = "table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Head
    </th>
    <td>
      cell
    </td>
</table>

<table class = "table separate">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Head
    </th>
    <td>
      cell
    </td>
</table>

<table class = "table none">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Head
    </th>
    <td>
      cell
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark it as the answer when/if you can so I can get some more meaningless Internet points.

Comment: Just done it now!

Answer (score 0):

CSS reads from top to bottom
if the class
`td, th, table {   border-collapse: collapse;   border: 1px solid #999; }`
is written after

```
table.cancellation {     border: none;    }
```

Then it will take the properties of the one that comes at the very last in your code!

If this isn't the case then you can use "border: none !important" as it has the highest rank among everything else

In case both of these methods don't work then I suggest you show me the bigger picture as in type in your related HTML and complete CSS of the div

Comment: even if reads top to bottom (cascade) the specificity  overrides cascade